# Autowire setter override with Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

Consider the following class:

```
public class MyBean {
    private A a;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

There are cases when one need need to override the autowired injection, for example when Spring cannot find a single candidate for the injection. In XML I can have the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="first" class="my.pkg.AImpl"/>
    <bean id="second" class="my.pkg.AImpl"/>
    <bean id="myBeanFirst" class="my.pkg.MyBean">
        <property name="a" ref="first"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="myBeanSecond" class="my.pkg.MyBean">
        <property name="a" ref="second"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Is there a way to do the same thing with Java Config? The following doesn't work (and I understand why) because Spring try to autowire the property after returning from myBean method and it fails with NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public A first() {
        return new AImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public A second() {
        return new AImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBeanFirst(A first) {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        myBean.setA(first);
        return myBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBeanSecond(A second) {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        myBean.setA(first);
        return myBean;
    }
}
```

To modify the MyBean class isn't always an option, for example because it comes from an external library.
Is this a case where I have to use XML configuration?

Thanks,
Andrea Polci

**Update**
Thanks for the two solution so fare (injection by name, and use of @Primary) but they don't solve my use case so I need to be more specific I think.

In my use case the MyBean class comes from an external library so any change to it is not possible. I also need to have more than one instance of MyBean, each one injecting different intances of the A interface. I've update the code above to reflect this (both xml and java).

Is there any solution using java config? Is it possible to avoid the autowire of the dependency on MyBean? (Only on the beans of that class, not disablig autowiring completely for every bean in the context)

Comment: Can the one that voted down this question explain why, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here it goes, I believe this answer will satisfy your needs.

What we need is an implementation of `MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor` that will set the correct value for the property `a` of class `MyBean`. This can be done by the following class

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor {


    @Override
    public void postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition, Class<?> beanType, String beanName) {
        if(beanName.equals("myBeanFirst")) {
            beanDefinition.getPropertyValues().add("a", getMyBeanFirstAImpl());
        }
        else if(beanName.equals("myBeanSecond")) {
            beanDefinition.getPropertyValues().add("a", getMyBeanSecondAImpl());
        }
    }

    private Object getMyBeanFirstAImpl() {
        return new AImpl();
    }

    private Object getMyBeanSecondAImpl() {
        return new AImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

As you can see the names of the beans here are hardcoded but they could be set in static final String that would be also used by the @Bean annotations in the following code

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {



    @Bean
    public MyBean myBeanFirst() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBeanSecond() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

}
```

You will notice in the following code that setA is not called in the MyBean creation methods, because no matter what value we set (or in this case don't set) will be overridden when Spring executes the bean post processor.

In case you need a default value for A (if for example you are injecting it in other beans), proceed to define a @Bean in the previous configuration

Comment: If this is the simpler way to do this with Java Config I think the real answer should be "use xml config in this case". Thanks the same.

Comment: I don't know if it's the simplest or not, there might be better answers!
However I do know that xml config works because xml config overrides any previous configuration.

Comment: @geoand - upvoting your answer, viable approach if the asker knew what he was doing.

Comment: @ike_love I've never said that this is not viable. What I mean is that if I need to define a custom post processor to set a dependency this is a sign that I'm trying to do something the framework isn't intendend to and I need to change my approach (for example use xml configuration in this case). Don't assume I'm the one that downvoted this answer, I'm not.

Comment: @geoand upvoted and accepted this answer since it's the only one that apply to my use case, but i changed my approach and gave up on trying to use Java Configuration in this case.

Comment: @AndreaPolci Thanks! This case is probably a good case where JavaConfig does not facilitate the developer

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple candidates for injection you can specify the default one by using @Primary on the bean you want to be the default AImpl. That way no changes are needed to MyBean

Comment: Also this doesn't always solve the problem. What if I need to have two instances of MyBean, with different instances of A injected in them? What I need, if exists, is a way to replicate in Java Config the behavior of xml config I've posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want myBeanFirst to use first, then just call `first()`. Same for myBeanSecond, want it to use second, then just call `second()` when setting A;

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public A first() {
        return new AImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public A second() {
        return new AImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBeanFirst() {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        myBean.setA(first());
        return myBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBeanSecond() {
        MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
        myBean.setA(second());
        return myBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work since after the bean has been created by myBeanFirst(), Spring try to inject the @Autowire annotated field (he doesn't know it has already been setted).
As already said I cannot modify MyBean to remove the annotation since it comes from an externa library.

Comment: I've only voted down this one because it isn't working. I'm not the one that voted down the other answer from you. I really appreciate the help, sorry if I gave a different impression. Also I wasn't complaining about the down vote, I was just curious on what was the reason and if I could do something about it.