# Qualify of Job to run with JobLauncherTestUtils not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I have a launch-context.xml that defines 7 different jobs, all of which have the same parent. They have names like "jobA", "jobB" and so on.

I tried:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/launch-context.xml", "/OurBatchKernelTestConfig.xml" })
 public class AllTest extends BaseRaptorBatchTest {

     @Autowired
     private JobLauncherTestUtils utils;

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier(value="jobA")
     private Job job;

     @Test
     public void testLaunch() {
         Properties p = new Properties(); // then I set these up.
         JobExecution je = utils.launchJob(paraCvter.getJobParameters(p));
     }
 }
```

This does not work.

I get an exception like:

```
 STDOUT [WARN ] [2015.04.15 11:14:42] support.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncherTestUtilsForSnapshot': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(org.springframework.batch.core.Job); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: coverageRuleBatch,generateMetricsSnapshotJob
```

I also tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658577/869809

and I tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36352437/869809

Neither of these work.

I can create a copy of my launch-content.xml and remove the other jobs. Then I refer to that in the annotation and all is good. But I then need 7 different xml files. Ick.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the exception's message, it appears that you need to disambiguate what bean in your Spring context should be autowired to the member variable `utils`. Something like this:

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(value="coverageRuleBatch")
 private JobLauncherTestUtils utils;
```

or this:

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier(value="generateMetricsSnapshotJob")
 private JobLauncherTestUtils utils;
```

should resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: So, first I wanted to use an auto-wired JobLauncherTestUtils instance and call setJob on it with the job desired. But auto-wiring the job ivar using the @Qualifier(value="jobA") did not work.

Comment: Second, I tried using a sub-class of JobLauncherTestUtils that included the set of my job. That did not work either.

Comment: Actually you are suggesting the same solution as the one in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36352437/869809, which I cited above. That did not work.

Comment: If autowiring is not working you might try constructor injection. Although I have had good success with autowire +qualifier

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your test config shouldn't instantiate more than 1 `Job` as JobLauncherTestUtils expect only one bean.

In order to workaround `JobLauncherTestUtils` limitations you can manage dependencies for it yourselves via constructor/setters as done in: [Spring Batch JUnit test for multiple jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217101/spring-batch-junit-test-for-multiple-jobs)

Alternatively you can subclass `JobLauncherTestUtils` and set `@Qualifier` on:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myChosenJobBeanName")
public void setJob(Job job) {
    this.job = job;
}
```

but you need to override it for each job you like to test. It is better to end with factory method.

You can launch job without `JobLauncherTestUtils`. Just study implementation. It is simple as:

```
getJobLauncher().run(this.job, jobParameters);
```

Also look to [How can I qualify an autowired setter that I don't "own"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655796/how-can-i-qualify-an-autowired-setter-that-i-dont-own)