# Spring Batch JUnit test for multiple jobs

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am having two jobs configured in one context file

```
<batch:job id="JobA" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abc">
            <batch:tasklet >
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor"  />
            </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>

    </batch:job>

<batch:job id="JobB" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="abc">
            <batch:tasklet >
                <batch:chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" processor="processor"  />
            </batch:tasklet>
      </batch:step>

    </batch:job>
```

When i am doing unit testing for the JobA using `JobLauncherTestUtils` and testing the job launch it is throwing an exception saying

```
No unique bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job;] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [JobA, JobB]
```

i tried using `@Qualifier` for autowire still the same thing. Where am i doing wrong here

edited

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:META-INF/spring/batch-test-context.xml" })
public class TestJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("JobA")
    private Job JobA;


    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;


    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        JobParameters jobParameters = getNextJobParameters(getJobParameters());
        assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, jobLauncherTestUtils.getJobLauncher().run(JobA, jobParameters));
    }


    private JobParameters getJobParameters() {
        JobParametersBuilder jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder();
        jobParameters.addString("param", "123");
        return jobParameters.toJobParameters();
    }


    private JobParameters getNextJobParameters(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        String jobIdentifier = jobLauncherTestUtils.getJob().getName();
        List<JobInstance> lastInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobIdentifier, 0, 1);
        JobParametersIncrementer incrementer = jobLauncherTestUtils.getJob().getJobParametersIncrementer();
        if (lastInstances.isEmpty()) {
            return incrementer.getNext(jobParameters);
        } else {
            List<JobExecution> lastExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(lastInstances.get(0));
            return incrementer.getNext(lastExecutions.get(0).getJobParameters());
        }
    }
}
```

exception was

```
No unique bean of type [org.springframework.batch.core.Job;] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [JobA, JobB]`
```

Comment: Add your test code and the full stack trace.

Answer (score 16):

Maybe late,

but I found for myself working solution: manual configuration of `JobLauncherTestUtils`:

```
@Inject
@Qualifier(value = "Job1")
private Job job;

@Inject
private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Inject
private JobRepository jobRepository;

private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

private void initailizeJobLauncherTestUtils() {
    this.jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
    this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
    this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.initailizeJobLauncherTestUtils();
}
```

with this you can control for which Job should JobLauncherTestUtils be applied. (by default it expects single Job configuration in context)

Comment: for me, it still runs both jobs. I have tried this solution as is. I don't kno what else to do.

Comment: For other's benefit. Remove `@SpringBatchTest` annotation with this approach. The mentioned annotation is injecting `JobLauncherTestUtils` automatically.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that spring tries to still create the jobLauncherTestUtils in the background. So, to avoid that fo mark your instance as  at `@MockBean`.
`@MockBean private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;`

Answer (score 5):

Because there is an `@Autowired` annotation on the setter for `JobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(Job job)` I had to use a MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor to set the property after the bean was created:

```
@Configuration
public class TestBatchConfiguration implements MergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("JobA")
    private Job job;

    @Bean(name="jtestl")
    public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
        JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
        return jobLauncherTestUtils;
    }

    /**
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22416140/autowire-setter-override-with-java-config
     * This is needed to inject the correct job into JobLauncherTestUtils
     */
    @Override
    public void postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition, Class<?> beanType, String beanName) {
        if(beanName.equals("jtestl")) {
            beanDefinition.getPropertyValues().add("job", getMyBeanFirstAImpl());
        }
    }

    private Object getMyBeanFirstAImpl() {
        return job;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that spring tries to still create the jobLauncherTestUtils in the background. So, to avoid that fo mark your instance as  at `@MockBean`.
`@MockBean private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;`

Answer (score 2):

Not answer to original problem, but using below code we have avoided reuse of JobLauncherTestUtils during sequential run of test cases in same class.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

This indicates Junit to clean up and re construct context after each run.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion of this on the [spring-batch github site](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3699#issuecomment-634590923).
The comment by [manumouton](https://github.com/manumouton) sums up what worked for me. Basically, remove `@SpringBatchTest` annotation from your test class if you are using it, and, for each Job you want to test, add a Bean in your test configuration to provide a separate JobLauncherTestUtils implementation that overrides the `@Autowired` setJob(Job job) method to add `@Qualifier` that identifies the particular job you want to target.

This is similar to [ilya-dyoshin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450951/ilya-dyoshin)'s solution, but better satisfies one's obsession with IOC.

I'm just going to copy and paste the code from github for convenience:

```
@Configuration
static class MyTestConfiguration {
@Bean
public JobLauncherTestUtils myJobLauncherTestUtils() {
  return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setJob(@Qualifier("mySpecificJobQualifier") Job job) {
      super.setJob(job);
    }
  };
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have two similar beans declared in bean configuration file.
To fix above problem, you need `@Qualifier("JobA")` and `@Qualifier("JobB")` to tell Spring about which bean should auto wired to which job.

Comment: Job Bean is autowired in the JobLauncherTestUtils, which expect single bean per batch.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating JobLauncherTestUtils for each job separately (groovy):

```
@TestConfiguration class BatchJobTestConfiguration {

@Autowired
@Qualifier('job1')
private Job job1

@Autowired
@Qualifier('job2')
private Job job2

@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepository;

@Bean
JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SyncTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean(name = 'jobLauncherTestUtilsJob1')
JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtilsSyncEndUserJob() {
    new JobLauncherNoAutowireTestUtil(
            job: job1,
            jobLauncher: jobLauncher()
    )
}

@Bean(name = 'jobLauncherTestUtilsJob2')
JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtilsenewCaseJob() {
    new JobLauncherNoAutowireTestUtil(
            job: job2,
            jobLauncher: jobLauncher()
    )
}
```

Then add this into your test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [BatchJobTestConfiguration])
...
@Autowired
@Qualifier('jobLauncherTestUtilsJob1')
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils
...
when:
def jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob()
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Spring Boot I would recommend to separate the two jobs into separate contexts using `@EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)`

Jobs can then be tested separately by providing only the specific configuration with `@SpringBootTest(classes = { JobAConfiguration.class, ... })`

There is a great and comprehensive example including separate test classes for separate jobs at https://github.com/desprez/springbatch-modular (not by me, kudos to the author).

Answer (score 1):

I tried all these solution mentioned but nothing worked. After that i tried below

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(value = { SPRING_PROFILE_TEST })
public class SIJobTest {

@Autowired
@Qualifier( "jobLauncherTestUtilsForTccLimit" )
protected JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
```

in test case calling launch job

```
 jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(params);
```

My Bean creation of jobLauncherTestUtils

```
 @Configuration
public class SpringBatchTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public static JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtilsForTccLimit() {
        return new TccLimitJobLauncherTestUtils();
    }

    public static class TccLimitJobLauncherTestUtils extends JobLauncherTestUtils {

        @Override
        @Autowired
        public void setJob( @Qualifier("tcclimit_report") final Job job ) {
            super.setJob( job );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that doesn't involve `JobLauncherTestUtils` at all. Looking at that class it didn't gave me much beside headaches.

First of all add an abstract base class:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Sql(
    executionPhase = BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
    scripts = {"classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"})
@Sql(
    executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD,
    scripts = "classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-h2.sql")
abstract class AbstractBatchIntegrationTest {

  @Autowired private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired private JobExplorer jobExplorer;

  protected JobExecution startJob(final Job job) throws JobExecutionException {
    return jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParametersBuilder(jobExplorer).getNextJobParameters(job).toJobParameters());
  }
}
```

**Hint:** Add whatever Test-Annotations work for you. You can make use of @SpringBatchTest for example.
**Note:** As you can see the one-liner in `startJob()` is all i need from `JobLauncherTestUtils`

The actual test looks like this:

```java
class SampleJobIntegrationTest extends AbstractBatchIntegrationTest {
    
  @Autowired private Job sampleJob;
    
  @Test
  void shouldStartSampleJob() throws Exception {
    // given
    // maybe prepare the database?
    
    // when
    final var jobExecution = startJob(sampleJob);
    
    // then
    assertThat(jobExecution.getExitStatus()).isEqualTo(ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
  }
}
```

**BTW:** Many "guides" suggest to use `@Qualifier` when autowiring your beans. Thats actually not necessary when you name your field correct.
Above example will work as long as you have a job bean somewhere in your production code:

```java
  @Bean
  public Job sampleJob() {
    return jobBuilder
        .get("")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .flow(
            ...)
        .end()
        .build();
  }
```

Pro: Clean and small test. Logic to start the job and all needed annotations are hidden in superclass.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem because we also use `spring-cloud-configuration` in the project, which needs `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and then loads the entire Spring Boot context, so multiple jobs are loaded in the context.

The solution we came to is close to the one provided by *Ilya Dyoshin*, with constructor injection and Junit 5 :

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyJobConfigTest {

    private final JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    public MyJobConfigTest(Job jobNumber1, JobLauncher jobLauncher, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils = new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        this.jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(jobNumber1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this requires boot, but...

Assuming you have 2 `Job` Spring beans, named `jobA` and `jobB`, you want to test `jobA`.

```java
@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(MyMainClass.class)  // load the application context as usual
@ContextConfiguration(JobATest.class)     // load @Bean definition(s) below
class JobATest {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    Job testJob(Job jobA) { // parameter name should be the component name
                            // otherwise you can use @Qualifier
        return jobA;
    }

    // ... test methods
}
```

Explained, this configuration does:

1. create a third `Job` bean marked as primary, hence `JobLauncherTestUtils` gets autowired with it;
2. make the bean definition available to the current `@SpringBatchTest` class only.